# How does clipping multiple times in the same path differ from the same clips in multiple paths?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Here are two side by side images formed, using the same clips, except for one image all clips are on the same path (right) and for the second image all clips are on separate paths (left):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}
    \clip (210:0.75) circle (1); 
    \clip (330:0.75) circle (1);
    \clip (90:0.75) circle (1);
    \fill[blue] (210:0.75) circle (1);
    \end{scope}
    \draw (210:0.75) circle (1) node{A}; 
    \draw (330:0.75) circle (1) node{B};
    \draw (90:0.75) circle (1) node{C};
    
    \begin{scope}[xshift=3.5cm]
    \clip (210:0.75) circle (1) (330:0.75) circle (1) (90:0.75) circle (1); 
    \fill[blue] (210:0.75) circle (1);
    \end{scope}
    \draw[xshift=3.5cm] (210:0.75) circle (1) node{A}; 
    \draw[xshift=3.5cm] (330:0.75) circle (1) node{B};
    \draw[xshift=3.5cm] (90:0.75) circle (1) node{C};
    
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

How does Tikz read clipping in one path differently from clipping in multiple paths to produce this difference?

Comment: A path calculates a union of its various components. Multiple 'clip' operations compute the intersection of paths.

Comment: + it's useless to `\clip (210:0.75) circle (1)` then `\fill[blue] (210:0.75) circle (1);`. You can only clip both the or=ther circles.

Comment: You might also enjoy `\fill[blue, even odd rule] (210:0.75) circle (1) (330:0.75) circle (1) (90:0.75) circle (1);`.